# Does USGS Landsat 8 Collection 2 Tier 1 TOA Reflectance need cloud mask before NDVI computation

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, landsat-8

For computing the NDVI I want to use USGS Landsat 8 Collection 2 Tier 1 TOA Reflectance `LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA` does it need cloud masking or any other form of ''cleaning'' before I can use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Landsat 8 Collection 2 encompasses Level-1 (top of atmosphere reflectance) and Level-2 (atmospherically corrected surface reflectance) products. Since Landsat 8 Collection 2 level-2 correspond to surface reflectance and;

> corrected for the temporally, spatially and spectrally varying
> scattering and absorbing effects of atmospheric gases, aerosols, and
> water vapor

it should be used to generate NDVI.

However, you need to apply scaling factor i.e., `0.0000275 + -0.2` for Level-2 before calculating NDVI. You should mask pixels which are contaminated by clouds and shadows as well.

Here, I would recommend a worth reading article "[A survival guide to Landsat preprocessing](https://esajournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/ecy.1730)" for further enlightenment.

More information about Landsat Collection 2 Level-2 Science Products can be accessed from [here](https://www.usgs.gov/landsat-missions/landsat-collection-2-level-2-science-products).

Comment: Are you sure about the scaling factor for `LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA` on GEE? I am new to all of this but here are two observations: 1) the GEE guide [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/tutorial_api_06) shows how to calculate NDVI and does not use any scaling. Just `image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDVI')` where `image` is from the `LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA` collection.  2) Before scaling, values should be between 1-65455 but I see values such as 0.2 for B5 in my quick check.

Comment: Please see the link added in answer for more information

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  There are examples in the code editor for doing cloud and shadow masking.