# (GEE) Constant value in Chart after applying scaling factor to LANDSAT

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, landsat-8

After applying a scaling factor to my LANDSAT collection 2 level 2 data the values seem to be off.

[image: screen capture of code and output]

```
var addNDVI = function(image) {
      var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['SR_B4', 'SR_B5']).rename('NDVI');
      return image.addBands(ndvi);
    };


var collection1 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterBounds(sch)
    .filterDate('2013-01-01', '2023-01-01')
    .select(['SR_B4', 'SR_B5'])
    .map(addNDVI).select('NDVI');

collection1 = collection1.map(
  function(img){
    var rescaled_NDVI = img.select('NDVI').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2)
    .rename('NDVI_rescaled')
    return img.addBands(rescaled_NDVI);
  }
);
  
var series1 = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
    collection1, sch, ee.Reducer.mean(), 'NDVI_rescaled', 30, 'system:time_start', 'label')
        .setChartType('ScatterChart')
        .setOptions({
          title: 'L5_SCH_1984-01-01_1986-12-31',
          vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'},
          lineWidth: 1,
          pointSize: 4,
});

Map.addLayer(sch, {color: 'FF0000'});
print(series1);
//var palette = {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']};
Map.addLayer(collection1);
```

Comment: How do you want the chart to look? `0.0000275` is very small value to multiply.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz I am very new to this, I assumed mostly positive values in the range of 0.2-0.8.

Comment: NDVI range is [-1, 1]. `-1*0.0000275-0.2 = -0.20000275` and `1*0.0000275-0.2 = -0.1999725`. So NDVI_rescaled range would be [-0.20000275, -0.1999725]. You need to define proper number to multiply and add.

Comment: But these are the official rescaling factors from the LANDSAT website

Comment: They are for reflectance values whose range is 0-65455.

Comment: When I do not apply a rescaling factor all values are negative

Comment: @N_LLC In response to your previous question, scaling factor was provided.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/450920/does-usgs-landsat-8-collection-2-tier-1-toa-reflectance-need-cloud-mask-before-n/450927#450927

Comment: According to the chart, you seem to be getting a constant value. But it is not. To limit the axis, add `viewWindow: {min: -0.20001, max: -0.19999}` 
 into [`vAxis` option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbkKz.png). Result -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqprG.png

Comment: This answered the question, I am very thankful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the chart, you seem to be getting a constant value. But that's not true. If you limit the axis, you will see the result clearly. To limit the axis, add `viewWindow: {min: -0.20001, max: -0.19999}` into `vAxis` option.

```
    .setOptions({
      title: 'L5_SCH_1984-01-01_1986-12-31',
      vAxis: {title: 'NDVI', viewWindow: {min: -0.20001, max: -0.19999}}, //HERE
      lineWidth: 1,
      pointSize: 4,
```

Result:

[image]

---

**Old answer**:
If you want to scale ndvi values `[-1, 1]` to, for example, `[0, 1]`, use `ndvi * 0.5 + 0.5`.

```
var rescaled_NDVI = img.select('NDVI').multiply(0.5).add(0.5)
```

The result of the line above:

[image]

---

To scale a range `[min, max]` to `[a, b]` use this formula:

```
(b - a)(x - min)
----------------- + a
    max - min
```

The result for conversion `[-1, 1]` to `[0, 1]` is `ndvi * 0.5 + 0.5`.
Rescaling formula and additional explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5295202/5569709).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I would use the rescaling factor before computing the NDVI?

Comment: No, after computing the NDVI.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/time-series-modeling

In the example you find here they apply the rescaling before computing the NDVI

Comment: You said you wanted mostly positive values in the range of 0.2-0.8. Let's say 0-1. I've edited the answer.

Comment: No, I was expecting values in that range. When I found out the values were off I assumed that I had to apply a rescaling factor as is described in this table: https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/how-do-i-use-scale-factor-landsat-level-2-science-products

Comment: What I'm wondering is why GEE didn't scale the axis by values here.